# Function from W3Schools is breaking my script?

Tags: javascript, cookies

So I have a long chunk of JavaScript on my website's administrator panel. Almost everything appears to work... until I add this function! I got it from W3Schools, which is why I'm surprised. Despite all my staring and syntax-highlighting, though, I can't find any syntax errors or anything, so I have absolutely no idea why this is killing my script.

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++)
    {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x === c_name)
        {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, if I add this to the script, Firebug gives me a `Reference Error, FUNCTIONNAME is not defined`, with `FUNCTIONNAME` being whichever other function is called. HOWEVER, if I comment this code snippet out of the script, I don't receive the error anymore.

Why would this function be doing that? What's wrong with it?

Comment: First and foremost, [do not read anything from w3schools](http://w3fools.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, found the problem, and it actually wasn't related to the code snippet I was providing. Later along, when I was calling the script, it was part of an if statement, like so:

```
if (getCookie("menu_maindiv"))
{
     /*  ....  */
}
```

However, this did not appear to work. Setting a value to be equal to fixed the problem, like so:

```
if (getCookie("menu_maindiv") !== NULL)
{
     /*  ....  */
}
```

I'm surprised that this would fix it, but JavaScript has always been my weak point. Thanks anwyays, guys. :/

Answer (score 0):

unescape() is deprecated, could your browser not recognize it? Also, just try commenting out some lines of code until you narrow it down to where the error takes place.

Comment: Browsers still support it, it just breaks on some (or maybe all) non-ascii unicode.